# Embed full dashboard from Grafana in a web application using node.js

Tags: node.js, iframe, grafana, dashboard

I know how to embed the visualizations from the dashboard using Grafana one by one using different links (see image 1). But, I wonder if I can embed the whole dashboard only using a single link, and then display it in the HTML. My dashboard looks like this (see image 2) for now.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]